# Cloudflare API enable firewall rule via curl

Tags: api, cloudflare

I have looked at https://api.cloudflare.com/#firewall-rules-update-firewall-rules however I am not sure how exactly I would update a firewall rule via a single curl command. The rule is already made I only need to either enable/disable it using my CF API key, CF Email and CF firewall-rule ID.

I have tried the following

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/ZONEID/firewall/rules/FIREWALLRULE" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: myemail@example.com" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: GLOBALAPIKEY" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"paused":"false"}'
```

it returns

```
{
  "result": null,
  "success": false,
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 10014,
      "message": "firewallrules.api.malformed_request_body"
    }
  ],
  "messages": []
}
```

But makes no changes

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Cloudflare API Documentation it seems that you're parsing the value of `paused` as a string instead of boolean.

[image]

This seems to be what's giving you the error below:

```json
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 10014,
      "message": "firewallrules.api.malformed_request_body"
    }
```

That said, I've tried to run it but the request still seems to be incomplete. No matter what I do the API seems to require parsing the `action`, the rule `id` and a `filter` which requires `filter id` and `paused` action.

```json
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "filter is a required field",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/0"
      }
    }
  ],
```

```json
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "invalid action provided",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/0"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Here's what I did:

1. Get the rule ID using the `GET zones/:zone_identifier/firewall/rules`

```json
curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/ZONEID/firewall/rules" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: ACCEMAIL" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: APIKEY" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Reply:

```json
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "RULEID",
      "paused": false,
      "description": "test",
      "action": "block",
      "filter": {
        "id": "FILTERID",
        "expression": "(http.host eq \"some.domain.com\")",
        "paused": false
      },
      "created_on": "2021-10-06T05:33:58Z",
      "modified_on": "2021-10-06T05:33:58Z"
    }
  ],
  "success": true,
  "errors": [],
  "messages": [],
  "result_info": {
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 25,
    "count": 1,
    "total_count": 1,
    "total_pages": 1
  }
```

2. Once you get the ID, use the following, replacing values accordingly, to update the rule status.

```json
curl -X PUT "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/ZONEID/firewall/rules/RULEID" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: ACCEMAIL" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: APIKEY" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"action": "block","paused": true,"filter":{"id": "RULEID","paused":true}}'
```

Reply:

```json
{
  "result": {
    "id": "RULEID",
    "paused": true,
    "action": "block",
    "filter": {
      "id": "FILTERID",
      "expression": "(http.host eq \"some.domain.com\")",
      "paused": true
    },
    "created_on": "2021-10-06T05:33:58Z",
    "modified_on": "2021-10-06T05:53:51Z",
    "index": 0
  },
  "success": true,
  "errors": [],
  "messages": []
}
```

And I can also confirm the Cloudflare Dashboard reflects this update.

[image]